# In C++, macro usage before semicolon in function declaration

Tags: c++, macros, declaration

Can anyone please explain me the following code:

```
    #ifndef SOME_DEF
        #define SOME_DEF
    #endif

    class base_class{    
        public:
        base_class() SOME_DEF;

        ~base_class() SOME_DEF;

        bool init(int arg1, int arg2) SOME_DEF;

    };
```

I am not able to understand the usage of macro after every function.

Comment: can you point us to the source where you found it please?

Comment: This is common when a file is supposed to be parsed by some other tool, and that tool needs some kind of "tag" for its processing. Qt makes frequent use of empty macros, for instance.

Comment: The code, I was looking is company proprietary code, so I can't share it. But yes,  comment about using empty macro as tag makes sense, as we are using c++  as a secondary language and accessing it through some fixed interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it does nothing, unless `SOME_DEF` is already defined somewhere else, for example:

```
#define SOME_DEF { cout << "default definition" << endl; }
```

If `SOME_DEF` is defined like that, then every function in your class that includes `SOME_DEF` will have that body.

Comment: Yes, in our case, we were setting some attributes via the Macro. Thanks.